# After an upgrade from 16.04 to 20.04 LTS my HP printer/scanner doesn't work anymore

Tags: hp, python3, scanner

I've upgraded from 16.04 to 20.04 and my HP printer/scanner Laserjet pro m479fdw doesn't work anymore.
It works fine using wifi direct, but using my domestic network, it doesn't work anymore. When I was running 16.04 I installed hplip-3.21.2.run. So when I upgraded to 20.04, as it didn't work, I installed hplip-3.21.8.run. But same result. I uninstalled it, then using Synaptic, I installed all hplip packages, but same result. I've tried to follow some tuto on youtube, specially to install the appropriate python files as I got error messages about it, but I'm sure I broke my system. Cups gives me error, sometimes it seems to be stopped.. Running "hp-doctor", these are the error messages I get : (I've got to delete most of the output as i can't post everything, my message was considerated as spam) :

```
hp-doctor  

HP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 3.20.3)
Self Diagnse Utility and Healing Utility ver. 1.0
Checking for Deprecated items....
No Deprecated items are found   


Checking for HPLIP updates....
error: Failed to locate hp-upgrade utility


Checking for Dependencies....
warning: ubuntu-20.04 version is not supported. Using ubuntu-19.10 versions dependencies to verify and install...

---------------
| SYSTEM INFO |
---------------

 Kernel: 5.4.0-88-generic #99-Ubuntu SMP Thu Sep 23 17:29:00 UTC 2021 GNU/Linux
 Host: celtes15
 Proc: 5.4.0-88-generic #99-Ubuntu SMP Thu Sep 23 17:29:00 UTC 2021 GNU/Linux
 Distribution: ubuntu 20.04
 Bitness: 64 bit


-----------------------
| HPLIP CONFIGURATION |
-----------------------

HPLIP-Version: HPLIP 3.20.3
HPLIP-Home: /usr/share/hplip
warning: HPLIP-Installation: Auto installation is not supported for ubuntu distro  20.04 version 

Current contents of '/etc/hp/hplip.conf' file:
# hplip.conf.  Generated from hplip.conf.in by configure.

[hplip]
version=3.20.3


Current contents of '/var/lib/hp/hplip.state' file:
[plugin]
installed = 1
eula = 1
version = 3.20.3



Current contents of '~/.hplip/hplip.conf' file:
[installation]
date_time = 10/13/21 06:37:27
version = 3.20.3


 <Package-name>        <Package-Desc>      <Required/Optional> <Min-Version> <Installed-Version> <Status>   <Comment>

-------------------------
| External Dependencies |
-------------------------

 error: cups          CUPS - Common Unix Printing System                           REQUIRED        1.1             -               INCOMPAT   'CUPS may not be installed or not running'
 gs                   GhostScript - PostScript and PDF language interpreter and previewer REQUIRED        7.05            9.50            OK         -
 xsane                xsane - Graphical scanner frontend for SANE                  OPTIONAL        0.9             0.999           OK         -
 scanimage            scanimage - Shell scanning program                           OPTIONAL        1.0             1.0.29          OK         -
 dbus                 DBus - Message bus system                                    REQUIRED        -               1.12.16         OK         -
 policykit            PolicyKit - Administrative policy framework                  OPTIONAL        -               0.105           OK         -
 network              network -wget                                                OPTIONAL        -               1.20.3          OK         -
 avahi-utils          avahi-utils                                                  OPTIONAL        -               0.7             OK         -

------------------------
| General Dependencies |
------------------------

 libjpeg              libjpeg - JPEG library                                       REQUIRED        -               -               OK         -
 cups-devel           CUPS devel- Common Unix Printing System development files    REQUIRED        -               -               OK         -
 cups-image           CUPS image - CUPS image development files                    REQUIRED        -               -               OK         -
 libpthread           libpthread - POSIX threads library                           REQUIRED        -               b'2.31'         OK         -
 libusb               libusb - USB library                                         REQUIRED        -               1.0             OK         -
 sane                 SANE - Scanning library                                      REQUIRED        -               -               OK         -
 sane-devel           SANE - Scanning library development files                    REQUIRED        -               -               OK         -
 libnetsnmp-devel     libnetsnmp-devel - SNMP networking library development files REQUIRED        5.0.9           5.8             OK         -
 libcrypto            libcrypto - OpenSSL cryptographic library                    REQUIRED        -               1.1.1           OK         -
 python3X             Python 2.2 or greater - Python programming language          REQUIRED        2.2             3.8.10          OK         -
 python3-notify2      Python libnotify - Python bindings for the libnotify Desktop notifications OPTIONAL        -               -               OK         -
 error: python3-pyqt4-dbus PyQt 4 DBus - DBus Support for PyQt4                         OPTIONAL        4.0             -               MISSING    'python3-pyqt4-dbus needs to be installed'
 error: python3-pyqt4 PyQt 4- Qt interface for Python (for Qt version 4.x)         REQUIRED        4.0             -               MISSING    'python3-pyqt4 needs to be installed'
 python3-dbus         Python DBus - Python bindings for DBus                       REQUIRED        0.80.0          1.2.16          OK         -
 python3-xml          Python XML libraries                                         REQUIRED        -               2.2.9           OK         -
 python3-devel        Python devel - Python development files                      REQUIRED        2.2             3.8.10          OK         -
 python3-pil          PIL - Python Imaging Library (required for commandline scanning with hp-scan) OPTIONAL        -               8.3.2           OK         -
 python3-reportlab    Reportlab - PDF library for Python                           OPTIONAL        2.0             3.6.1           OK         -

--------------
| COMPILEDEP |
--------------

 libtool              libtool - Library building support services                  REQUIRED        -               2.4.6           OK         -
 gcc                  gcc - GNU Project C and C++ Compiler                         REQUIRED        -               9.3.0           OK         -
 make                 make - GNU make utility to maintain groups of programs       REQUIRED        3.0             4.2.1           OK         -

---------------------
| Python Extentions |
---------------------

 cupsext              CUPS-Extension                                               REQUIRED        -               3.20.3          OK         -
 hpmudext             IO-Extension                                                 REQUIRED        -               3.20.3          OK         -

----------------------
| Scan Configuration |
----------------------

 hpaio                HPLIP-SANE-Backend                                           REQUIRED        -               3.20.3          OK         'hpaio found in /etc/sane.d/dll.conf'
 scanext              Scan-SANE-Extension                                          REQUIRED        -               3.20.3          OK         -

------------------------------
| DISCOVERED SCANNER DEVICES |
------------------------------

device `hpaio:/net/HP_LaserJet_300_colorMFP_M375nw?ip=192.168.0.22' is a Hewlett-Packard HP_LaserJet_300_colorMFP_M375nw all-in-one
device `escl:https://192.168.1.22:443' is a ESCL HP Color LaserJet Pro M478f-9f [D68EE1] SSL flatbed scanner
device `escl:http://192.168.1.22:8080' is a ESCL HP Color LaserJet Pro M478f-9f [D68EE1] flatbed scanner
device `hpaio:/net/HP_LaserJet_300_colorMFP_M375nw?ip=192.168.0.22' is a Hewlett-Packard HP_LaserJet_300_colorMFP_M375nw all-in-one
device `escl:https://192.168.1.22:443' is a ESCL HP Color LaserJet Pro M478f-9f [D68EE1] SSL flatbed scanner
device `escl:http://192.168.1.22:8080' is a ESCL HP Color LaserJet Pro M478f-9f [D68EE1] flatbed scanner


--------------------------
| DISCOVERED USB DEVICES |
--------------------------

No devices found.

---------------------------------
| INSTALLED CUPS PRINTER QUEUES |
---------------------------------

Type: Unknown
Device URI: lpd://BRW001FE1CA01C1/BINARY_P1


Type: Printer
Device URI: hp:/net/HP_LaserJet_300_colorMFP_M375nw?ip=192.168.0.22
Required plug-in status: Installed
error: Unable to communicate with device (code=12): hp:/net/HP_LaserJet_300_colorMFP_M375nw?ip=192.168.0.22
error: unable to open channel
error: Communication status: Failed


Type: Fax
Device URI: hpfax:/net/HP_LaserJet_300_colorMFP_M375nw?ip=192.168.0.22
Required plug-in status: Installed
error: Unable to communicate with device (code=12): hpfax:/net/HP_LaserJet_300_colorMFP_M375nw?ip=192.168.0.22
error: unable to open channel
error: Communication status: Failed

--------------
| PERMISSION |
--------------

Missing Required Dependencies
-----------------------------
error: 'libcups2' package is missing or 'cups' service is not running.
error: 'python3-pyqt4' package is missing/incompatible 
error: 'gtk2-engines-pixbuf' package is missing/incompatible 
Missing Optional Dependencies
-----------------------------
error: 'python3-dbus.mainloop.qt' package is missing/incompatible 


ENTER SUDO PASSWORD
-------------------
Please enter the sudoer (fm)'s password: 

Checking Permissions....


Checking for Configured Queues....
No Queue added

warning: No Queue(s) configured.


Checking for HP Properitery Plugin's....
Plugin's already installed
 

Checking for Printer Status....
error: '' Printer is either Powered-OFF or Failed to communicate.
Turn On Printer and re-run hp-doctor

Diagnose completed...
```

As the computer is a laptop, I bring it to different locations, and those two printers/fax HP Laserjet 300 are elsewhere.

When I want to install that HP 479fdw printer, I get an error message :

```
--
  0*        usb         Universal Serial Bus (USB)                                
  1         net         Network/Ethernet/Wireless (direct connection or JetDirect)

Enter number 0...1 for connection type (q=quit, enter=usb*) ? 1

Using connection type: net

error: No device selected/specified or that supports this functionality.
```

And I can ping it with no problem.

So if someone has an idea and a step by step process to make it work, it will be a great help. thanks

Comment: Which HPLIP version was used in 16.04 LTS? How did you installed it?

Comment: How did you upgrade? 16.04->20.04 is not a supported upgrade path. Any reason you tagged  [`python3`](https://askubuntu.com/tags/python3/info)?

Comment: I upgraded from 16.04 to 18.04, then 18.04 to 20.04. I tagged python3 because I got warnings about it, and hplip wanted pyqt5. I read comments about installing PyQt5 using python3

Comment: Using 16.04 LTS, I used hplip-3.21.2.run, because it was the only I founded to make it works.

Comment: How to get rid of that message when running hp-check  `error: cups          CUPS - Common Unix Printing System                           REQUIRED        1.1             -               INCOMPAT   'CUPS may not be installed or not running'. But cups is well installed

Comment: HPLIP is not required with your device. See https://wiki.debian.org/CUPSQuickPrintQueues

Comment: Did not work for me anymore either, listed as USB device but not found by HP setup software. Same printer also stopped working with Mac and Windows 10 drivers, but it does work, when connecting the printer via ethernet cable to my wifi router (FritzBox) and making it available in the local network (device list in router configuration opens an HP web interface to configure the printer).